# To fetch the nth character of a fibbonacci series using python

Tags: python-3.x

A fibonacci series is the series in which the kth elementh is the sum of (k-1)th and (k-2)th
element.
It usually goes like this: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55.....

Now let us create a number, which is infinite length long, and has the fibonacci
numbers all appended to each other, i.e.1123581321...

Based on the above definition, I want to find the 1000th character in this
number.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide more information (code) that demonstrates what you try to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer for the above questions. Thanks

```
a=-1; 
b=1;
c=0;
sb = ""
while(len(sb) <=1000):
    c=a+b
    sb = sb + c.__str__()
    a=b
    b=c

i = int(input())
print("%sth character is: %s"% (i,sb[i]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
Number = int(input("Enter the number : "))
def fibonacci(Num):
    if(Num==0):
        return 0
    elif(Num==1):
        return 1
    else:
         return (fibonacci(Num-1) +  fibonacci(Num-2));
for j in range(0,Number):
    f = fibonacci(j)
    print(f)
```

Comment: your answer returns nth Fibonacci number, instead of nth character from "the fibonacci numbers all appended to each other, i.e.1123581321..." as requested in the question.